# UIImage takes up much more memory than its NSData

Tags: ios, memory, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm loading a `UIImage` from `NSData` with the following code

```
var image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

However, there is a weird behavior.

At first, I used png data, and the `NSData` was about 80kB each.

When I set `UIImage` with the data, the `UIImage` took up 128kb each.

(Checked with Allocation instrument, the size of `ImageIO_PNG_Data`)

Then I changed to use jpeg instead, and the `NSData` became about 7kb each.

But still, the `UIImage` is 128kb each, so when displaying the image I get no memory advantage! (The `NSData` reduced to 80kb -> 7kb and still the `UIImage` takes up the same amount of memory)

It is weird, why the `UIImage` should take up 128kb when the original data is just 7kb?

Can I reduce this memory usage by `UIImage` without shrinking the size of the `UIImage` itself??

Note that I'm not dealing with high resolution image so resizing the image is not an option (The `NSData` is already 7kb!!)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access the `NSData`, it is often compressed (with either `PNG` or `JPEG`). When you use the `UIImage`, there is an uncompressed pixel buffer which is often 4 bytes per pixel (one byte for red, green, blue, and alpha, respectively). There are other formats, but it illustrates the basic idea, that the JPEG or PNG representations can be compressed, when you start using an image, it is uncompressed.

In your conclusion, you say that resizing not an option and that the `NSData` is already 7kb. I would suggest that resizing *should* be considered if the resolution of the image is greater than the resolution (the points of the `bounds`/`frame` times the scale of the device) of the `UIImageView` in which you're using it. The question of whether to resize is not a function of the size of the `NSData`, but rather the resolution of the view. So, if you have a 1000x1000 pixel image that you're using in a small thumbview in a table view, then regardless of how small the JPEG representation is, you should definitely resize the image.

Comment: Thanks! I thought 7kb was so small compared to 128kb and 128kb is so neat (=2^7) so there might be something behind this.. and well there wasn't!! Stupid mistake of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. When the image is stored as `NSData`, it is compressed (usually using PNG or JPG compression). When it's a `UIImage`, the image is decompressed, which allows it to be drawn quickly on the screen.